# Get link under div class JSOUP

Tags: android, html, dom, jsoup

I have following html:

```
<!-- other html -->
<div class="my_class_name_1" style="padding-bottom: 125%;"><img alt="lorem ipsum dolor sit" class="my_class_name_2" decoding="auto" sizes="111px" srcset="https:/link1.jpg def1,https:/link2.jpg def2,https:/link1.jpg def3" src="https:/link3.jpg" style=""></div>
<!-- other html -->
```

from here I nedd to get only link from src `https:/link3.jpg` can't get it, any help is apreciated.

In whole html doc only once is `<div class="my_class_name_1"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"my_class_name_1\" style=\"padding-bottom: 125%;\"><img alt=\"lorem ipsum dolor sit\" class=\"my_class_name_2\" decoding=\"auto\" sizes=\"111px\" srcset=\"https:/link1.jpg def1,https:/link2.jpg def2,https:/link1.jpg def3\" src=\"https:/link3.jpg\" style=\"\"></div>");
System.out.println(doc.select(".my_class_name_1 img").first().attr("src"));
```

Output:

```
https:/link3.jpg
```